# round to even not consistently applied?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, rounding

*(Context: I'm writing a lightweight printf() for embedded applications, and I want it to behave like the real printf() when practical.)*

I understand that gcc and other well-behaved libraries use "round half to even" (aka "Banker's rounding") to prevent statistical bias in the following case:

```
printf("%0.0f %0.0f %0.0f %0.0f\n", 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5);
=> 0 2 2 4
```

So it surprised me that the same rounding rules are not applied for other precisions:

```
printf("%0.1f %0.1f %0.1f %0.1f\n", 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35);
=> 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

Is this expected behavior?  I would have expected:

```
=> 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.4
```

Can someone versed in numerical computation explain which is the desired behavior, and why?

(Note: see http://rextester.com/IUXDW9788 for live example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the input numbers, not the format.

0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, and 0.25 are all exactly representable in IEEE 754 64-bit binary, the most likely implementation for C double, so the round-to-even rule applies.

The closest representable value to 0.05 is 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125, which is closer to 0.1 than to 0.0

The closest representable value to 0.15 is 0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375, which is closer to 0.1 than to 0.2.

The closest representable value to 0.35 is 0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, which is closer to 0.3 than to 0.4.

The round-to-even rule only applies to numbers that are **exactly** half way between two possible results, not to numbers that are even slightly closer to one of the possible results than to the other.

Comment: Nice.  Makes perfect sense once you remember what's going on under the hood.  Thank you for the clear answer.